# Sumar tiempo a un horario

Tags: php, html5

Buen día. Tengo un problema y espero me puedan apoyar.

Tengo que registrar un campo en la bd digamos con 4 horas y en un campo de `html` se va a registrar un horario de inicio de una tarea digamos 4:00pm en un campo `type="time"` y lo que tengo que hacer es que al seleccionar una hora en el campo de `html` en automático en otro campo me de la suma de las 4 horas que obtuve desde la bd.

### Espero ser claro y me puedan apoyar. Gracias de antemano

**Base de datos:**

```
CREATE TABLE descripciones(
   idDescripcion INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   descripcion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   cantHoras INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (idDescripcion)
);

INSERT INTO `descripciones`(`descripcion`, `cantHoras`) VALUES 
('Horario de comida',3);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="time" name="horaInicio" value="06:00">
    <input type="time" name="horaFin">
</body>
</html>
```

Rn hora inicio el usuario pondrá una hora para comenzar y en automático se le sumaria las 3 horas en hora fin con el evento `onChange`.

Comment: Hola Jose Luis, podrias por favor publicar lo que has intentado, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Como dijo Ricardo, considera [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve].

Comment: Listo espero sea mas clara la explicacion